# Python - vectorized operation with scipy.stats.hypergeom

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have some intensive calculation to do involving hypergeomotric distribution and I'd like to know if there exists an implementation of this function that support 'real' vectorize calculation ? (Q1)
By 'real' I mean : not using the `np.vectorize` who seems to be implementing a `for` loop.

I know `R` implementation of the hypergeometric law allows for that kind of computation, which makes the code much more effcicient.

If it helps : I'm trying to duplicate an algorithm develop in R to Python, to compute exact confidence intervals for hypergeometric parameters. The concept was develop in the following paper :
http://www.wright.edu/~weizhen.wang/paper/37-2015jasa_wang.pdf

The solution involve iterating over all the possible combination of paremters to select the subset that satisfy to a specific condition.

(Q2) As an alternative, would it be possible to create my own udf using the definition of the law and the `np.choose` method but applied to vectors ?

(Q3) as a final option is it possible to call my script in R from Python ?

Thank you !